# MongoDB - how to find embeded documents from field with Object data type, and use them to query another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have got 2 collections. In 1st collection (coll1), sample document below having field `"header_datatype"` is of object BSON type

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd525741db04839bc65bf4d"), 
    "version" : NumberInt(1), 
    "isvalid" : true, 
    "validation_errors" : [],
    "data_file" : ObjectId("5dd66f4ccb8618406c90d8c9"), 
    "header_file" : ObjectId("5dd66e79cb8618406c90d8c8"), 
    "header_datatype" : {
        "PartId" : "number", 
        "Operator" : "string", 
        "County" : "string", 
        "FieldName" : "string", 
        "FormationTopName" : "string", 
        "Spud" : "string", 
        "ReleaseDate" : "string", 
        "DateofCompletion" : "string", 
        "TestedDate" : "string", 
        "TD" : "number", 
        "TVD" : "number", 
        "TotalFluid" : "number", 
        "TotalProppant" : "number", 
        "TopPerf" : "number", 
        "BottomPerf" : "number", 
        "FluidType" : "string", 
        "LateralLength" : "string", 
        "ChokeTopDescription" : "string", 
}, 
    "last_updated_by" : ObjectId("5dc0aed15399202590f34a54")
}
```

2nd collection (coll2), sample document as below:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "test9", 
    "name" : "Test Case", 
    "description" : "Test Case", 
    "isfinalized" : false, 
    "dataset" : "test9", 
    "dataset_version" : ObjectId("5dd525741db04839bc65bf4d"), 
    "last_updated_date" : ISODate("2012-11-25T09:50:38.640+0000"), 
    "header_datatype_details" : [
        {
            "PartId" : NumberLong(123456789), 
            "first_prod_date" : 2011.8333333333333, 
            "last_production_date" : 2012.0833333333333, 
            "date" : [
                2017.8333333333333, 
                2017.9166666666667, 
                2018.0, 
                2018.0833333333333, 
                2018.1666666666667, 
                2018.25, 
            ], 
            "last_real_life_event_index" : 4.0, 
            "Operator" : "OPER 1 LLC", 
            "County" : "Test 1", 
            "FieldName" : "VILLE DIST 1", 
            "FormationTopName" : "Topology 1", 
            "Spud" : "9/5/2010", 
            "ReleaseDate" : null, 
            "DateofCompletion" : "11/10/2010", 
            "TestedDate" : "11/20/2010", 
            "TD" : NumberInt(20833), 
            "TVD" : NumberInt(12833), 
            "TotalFluid" : 0.0, 
            "TotalProppant" : NumberInt(715000), 
            "TopPerf" : NumberInt(13100), 
            "BottomPerf" : NumberInt(20600), 
            "FluidType" : "GEL", 
            "LateralLength" : 7678.0, 
            "ChokeTopDescription" : "16/64", 
            "max_MD" : 20833.0
        }, 
        {
            "PartId" : NumberLong(987654321), 
            "first_prod_date" : 2010.25, 
            "last_production_date" : 2011.0, 
            "date" : [
                2016.25, 
                2016.3333333333333, 
                2016.4166666666667, 
            ], 
            "last_real_life_event_index" : 5.0, 
            "Operator" : "OPER 2", 
            "County" : "Test 2", 
            "FieldName" : "Unknown", 
            "FormationTopName" : "MOS 07078", 
            "Spud" : "1/27/2011", 
            "ReleaseDate" : null, 
            "DateofCompletion" : "4/30/2012", 
            "BottomPerf" : NumberInt(15916), 
            "FluidType" : "SLKW", 
            "LateralLength" : 6120.0, 
            "ChokeTopDescription" : "16/64", 
            "KOP" : 8847.0, 
            "max_MD" : 16927.0
        }
}
```

First task, I need to find ALL sub-document from coll1 where `"header_datatype"` contains `"string"`. So I am expecting

```
"Operator",
"County",
"FieldName",
"FormationTopName",
"Spud",
"ReleaseDate",
"DateofCompletion",
"TestedDate",
"FluidType",
"LateralLength",
"ChokeTopDescription"
```

Then as 2nd step, I would like to use above list of sub-elements to query 2nd collection (coll2), specifically in field `"header_datatype_details"` which is Array of objects.

Field `"header_datatype_details"` has most of the above sub-elements with value, for example in 1st array element `"header_datatype_details"`.`[0]`.`"FormationTopName"` has value as `"Topology 1"` and 2nd array element `"header_datatype_details".[1]."FormationTopName"` is "MOS 07078" etc.

I'd like to get **distinct** values from coll2 using ALL matching `"string"` values from `"header_datatype"` of coll1

I tried first task as

```
db.coll1.find({"header_datatype" : {$type : 2}}).forEach(printjson);
```

but not getting any/desired result

Could someone please guide me with how to accomplish both of those steps. Not sure if it's going to be $lookup aggregation or map-reduce operation.

Thank you

Comment: Also, "header_datatype" from coll1 will have different or dynamic (key-pair) values so may be it makes this little complicated.

Comment: For first task, I am getting fairly good results with below                                                         db.coll1.aggregate(
    [ 
  {$match: {_id: ObjectId("5dd525741db04839bc65bf4d")}},
  {$project: {header_datatype: {$objectToArray: "$header_datatype"}}},
  {$unwind: "$header_datatype"},
  {$match: {"header_datatype.v": "string"}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, "String Column" : "$header_datatype.k"}}
 ]
);

Comment: I would really appreciate Any guidance/hint. Thanks

Comment: Hello @user2683814 - I was wondering if you could kindly take a look at this question, and try to help when you have some time. Thank you & Regards